# some problems after move server on VPS

Tags: magento-2.1

I have been trying to solve the problem for several days.

I move whole working shop to VPS server. only the home page works,

http://b2b.nazwa.pl

when I click on the link I get error "not found".

also its not possible to run any command via SSH.

[image]

[image]

I install clean magento on the same server  and also I can not do any megento operation via SSH

Answer (score 0):

To getting closer to solving your problem you have to:

1. Do a `ls -alF` on the folder to find out the owner of the files
2. Do a `php -v` to see what php you have installed

Publish it in your original question, and many more can start helping you